# subquery - #1242 - Subquery returns more than 1 row

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle

Can I transform the following insertion in a way that it can handle case where the subquery returns more than 1 row? Only the first value is needed.

```
insert into mytable (column1,column2) values ('value1', select value from mytable2 where columnX='ABC')
```

---

Any idea to get this in oracle as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Oracle you can use a scalar sub-query with the insert...values syntax. For your example you would need to define "first value" and then write a query that only returns that.

If it is the minimum value:

```
insert into mytable (column1,column2) values (9, (select min(value) from mytable2 where columnX = 'ABC'));
```

If it is the value with the lowest id (assuming your table has an id field):

```
insert into mytable (column1,column2) values (9, 
                                              (select value
                                                 from (select value,
                                                              row_number() over (order by id) rn
                                                         from mytable2
                                                        where columnX = 'ABC')
                                                where rn = 1));
```

Answer (score 1):

Either use `INSERT ..VALUES` syntax  or `INSERT ..SELECT`, not both

```
insert into mytable (column1,column2)
select 'value1',value from mytable2 where columnX='ABC'
```

Answer (score 1):

if you always want to write value1 in there you could use

```
INSERT INTO mytable (column1,column2) (SELECT 'value1', value FROM mytable2 WHERE columnX='ABC')
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `insert . . . select`:

```
insert into mytable(column1, column2) 
    select 'value1', value
    from mytable2
    where columnX = 'ABC';
```

This will insert multiple matching rows, if they are found.

If you want only one row, then use `limit` at the end of the `select` query.